# Loading data into a Tuple using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, graph-databases

Can anyone help me understand the below error?

> java.sql.SQLException: Processing attribute att_name failed, keylist
> has different length with UDT fields  at
> com.tigergraph.jdbc.restpp.RestppPreparedStatement.executeBatch(RestppPreparedStatement.java:222)

Through Spark, I am trying to load values into a Tuple that I created in my graph(using JDBC Driver). The above-written tuple contains 5 attributes of various data types.

How do I need to keep the data for my tuple inside a DataFrame? I tried to keep them as an Array. But, the JDBC Driver didn't allow me to write an Array into the Graph DB. I then flattened the array into a string. But, I am getting an error:

> KeyList has a different length with UDT fields

Target DB: TigerGraph

Graph Name: MyGraph

Edge Name:Ed_testedge

Edge Attributes: c1,c2,mytuple(c3,c4,c5) //totally three attributes are present out of which one of them is a Tuple.[image: Sample Code]

Comment: Sharing some code would make the question much clearer.

Comment: @blackbishop, I have shared the sample code above. Basically, I want to understand how the data needs to be represented inside the dataframe for my tuple.